# Simulating Statistics from Regression Output

Tags: regression, inference, simulation

Hi I am looking at the case where I have estimated a simple regression model like so:

$$
y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \times T + \epsilon_{i}
$$

I assume that $T\in \{0,1\}$, think of a binary treatment, and that $y_{i}$ is a continuous outcome. Suppose I am interested in inference regarding $\beta_{1}/\beta_{0}$.

My understanding is that one way to go about this is via simulation (I looked into [this paper](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/abs/making-abs.shtml) from King et al. and Chapter 7 from Gelman and Hill's book), but I am a bit confused from what to draw/where to get from what to draw.

So generally speaking I do have the covariance matrix of coefficient estimates, say $\hat{\Sigma_{\beta}}$

1. Is it enough to draw $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_{1}$ with the help of this matrix, i.e. from a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\hat{\beta}, \hat{\Sigma_{\beta}})$?
2. In Gelman and Hill's book it seems like they draw $\sigma^{2}$ (the variance of the residuals) first, and then "recompute" $\hat{\Sigma_{\beta}}$  - why is this necessary (if it is)?

Comment: 1. yes, you can draw samples of $\beta$ from that multivariate normal; be aware this is an estimate of the true distribution (in practice the true distribution is impossible to know). 2. There is uncertainty in $\hat\sigma^2$, so sampling it is accounting for that uncertainty

Comment: thanks. but do i have to do this Gelman/Hill procedure which to me looks like I have to sample $\sigma^{2}$ first, then on that basis "re-derive" the distribution of $\beta$ and then sample from there?